# What is a word for a popular saying?

Tags: word-request

In China, there is such "saying" -- mixed-bloods are smarter. This may be right, may be not. Whatever, this is a kind of opinion and popular and people talk about it.

In Chinese we call it's a kind of `说法`, literally it means

> way of saying

But, in English `saying` means `proverb`. So it might be not right. And google translator gives this,

[image]

> This **statement** is very popular.

I don't think `statement` is right here.

How do you think about this?

Comment: Not sure, but I think you may be looking for _idiom_.

Comment: @MrLister. In west culture, "seeing a black cat or walking under a ladder leads to bad luck." that's also a 说法. Popular talk about by people. But not a proveb or idiom. I have asked some Chinese after this question. They gave me "view" or "common belief". Maybe those are the closest words.

Answer (score 3):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proverb):

> A proverb (from Latin: proverbium) is a simple, concrete, traditional saying that expresses a truth based on common sense or experience. Proverbs are often metaphorical and use formulaic language. Collectively, they form a genre of folklore.

So a **proverb** is the right word for a **sentence** often used to convey some message. **Maxim** could also be used as well as **passage**.